# Using SSIS in a cluster with BizTalk BAM

Tags: ssis, biztalk, biztalk-bam

We set up SQL server in a cluster. We then used one of the BizTalk servers and installed SSIS on it. We then configured BAM. Everything looked fine until we needed to run some of the SSIS jobs to archive stuff. They don't seem to have been created ...

We then tried to change the value in the MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml file and restart the SSIS on the BizTalk server and tested again but still no luck.

*What do we need to do and where do we need to change the value in the MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml file?*

In [this post](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/04/30/production-ready-bam-security-and-deployment/) Richard S. discusses problem but I can still can't seem to get it to work ...

Comment: Tuned out to be a stupid mistake with the hosts file ... 1+ for Shiraz as it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say exactly what the problem is based on your comment.

Couple of things you could check:

- Is your sql server database installed on a named instance?
- What rights does the account that you used to run the install have?